# Java XStream - Serialize/deserialize multiple types of arrays at root level

Tags: java, xstream

I have been looking for my scenario on SO and numerous other forums for two days now and tried several ideas in my code but nothing seems to produce my required xml, and deserialization has even more issues.

My app's user will have to save the project configuration to an xml file. Now the project has 3 different, distinct types of objects at root level, and not one. And there are multiple (yet fixed) number of objects of each root. Each object of each root further has other kinds of objects inside them (this part works perfectly well). So hierarchy is like this:

```
public static AA a[] = new AA[Global.MAX1];
public static BB b[] = new BB[Global.MAX2];
public static CC c[] = new CC[Global.MAX3];
```

Now as my app proceeds, user creates and populates all the objects of these arrays which are populated in a JTree. When he wishes to save or at app exit time, whole project's configuration (created objects) are to be saved to .xml file to be retrieved later as they're right now, for example to populate the same JTree.

**@What I tried:**
All the examples that I saw have just one top level element. Since I didn't want to create 3 different config files for each project, so I faked a top level element called Domain like this:

```
@XStreamAlias("Area")
public final class Domain {
    public static Domain domain = null;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    public String name = "Area";

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "aas")
    public static AA a[] = new AA[Global.MAX1];

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "bbs")
    public static BB b[] = new BB[Global.MAX2];

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "ccs")
    public static CC c[] = new CC[Global.MAX3];

    private Domain () { } // private so that it cannot be initialized by using {new domain();}

    public static Domain getInstance() { // singleton
        if (domain == null)
            domain = new Domain();
        return domain;
    }
}
```

But now at project save time, if I use following code to serialize:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
xml += lnSep + xStream.toXML(Domain.getInstance()); // or define a domain object and use
xml += lnSep + xStream.toXML(Domain.a);             // that to pass data to toXML()
xml += lnSep + lnSep + xStream.toXML(Domain.b);     // with same final effect
xml += lnSep + lnSep + xStream.toXML(Domain.c);
```

Then I get following xml (trimmed for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Area id="1" name="Area"/>
<aa-array id="1">
    <aa id="2">
    </aa>
</aa-array>

<bb-array id="1">
    <bb id="2">
    </bb>
</bb-array>

<cc-array id="1">
    <cc id="2">
    </cc>
</cc-array>
```

Look how it ends the domain object's xml on same line instead of closing after the `cc-array` (as required by me). Whereas if I use just the following code:

```
Domain domain = Domain.getInstance();
String xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
xml2 += lnSep + xStream.toXML(domain);
```

It (annoyingly) produces just the following in XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Area id="1" name="Area"/>
```

It seems that the arrays defined inside Domain class are not at all being treated as Domain's contained objects.

Thanks for your patience. Any ideas? Do I have to create marshal and unmarshall methods specifically? If yes... too cumbersome.. kindly guide for such a scenario... an object having one string and 3 array objects.

And Oh, btw, deserialization problems start after this serialization problem is done away with; as my aim is to get back the Domain object to fully populate my JTree.

**A Side Question:** Why `itemFieldName = "aas"` has no effect??

Answer (score 0):

My bad... I made my arrays `static` so that they could be accessed from the whole app. And it is nowhere mentioned in XStream's documentation/on-site tutorials that static members are not serialized/deserialized.

On just an impulse, i made my arrays non-static. Many changes spurred up in the whole app wherever I was accessing these arrays. I had to use `Domain.getInstance().ArrayName` to access the array that was formerly being accessed as `Domain.ArrayName`. After I had removed all the errors... wow... same xstream code that i had written more than 2 days ago started working without any change. Now my whole project is being serialized to XML using

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
xml += lnSep + xStream.toXML(domain);
```

and being de-serialized using

```
Domain domain = (Domain) xStream.fromXML(xml);
```

XStream is gr8! I wrote this answer to benefit any future users.